# Finding Eigenvectors for 2x2 matrix, with a zero row

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't find the eigenvectors for matrices like \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&-4\end{bmatrix}

I get following equations: 0x+0y = 0 and 0x-4y = 0. How am I supposed to solve y and x from these kind of equations in order to find the eigenvector?

Comment: $0x-4y=0$ just means $y=0$. Can you finish after that?

Comment: For a triangular matrix, your eigenvalues are the diagonals. Now, do you think that the eigenvalue $0$ has a unique eigenvector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the eigenvalues you are solving the equation

$$\left( \begin{array}{c  c} 0 & 0 \\0 & -4 \end{array} \right)\left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array}\right) = \lambda \left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array}\right)$$

which is equivalent to

$$\left(\begin{array}{c  c} -\lambda & 0 \\0 & -4-\lambda \end{array} \right) \left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 0 \end{array}\right)$$

Now a matrix that sends all vectors to zero has zero determinant, so

$$-\lambda(-4-\lambda) = 0$$

So the eigenvalues are 0 and -4.

Substitute each back in in turn; for 0 you get y=0, for -4 you get x = 0.

SO example unit eigenvectors are

$$\left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\ 0 \end{array}\right)$$ and $$\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 1 \end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Bear in mind that we are really talking about eigenspaces, since multiples of an eigenvector is still an eigenvector.

Comment: Thus, Rellek, no eigenvector is unique, since they are always a member of a linear subspace of eigenvectors for the same eigenvalue. IF the eigenvalue is repeated, that subspace is of greater dimension than 1.

Comment: Up to linear dependence is implied. It is clear that no eigenvector is unique, but can independent vectors satisfy the same eigenvalue? Of course. Take the 2x2 vector of zeros. You have a dependent matrix with nondistinct eigenvalues, yet can always have a set of eigenvectors spanning $R^2$.

Comment: I think we're in agreement here, since the zero matrix has a twice repeated eigenvalue of zero, thus a 2-d eigenspace (being the whole space). However in this case of course we have two independent 1-d eigenspaces